# Checklist for making sure your writing is Atomic?

Tags: style, technique

#### Question:

Can someone please give me a list of things to check when reviewing a document to make sure that it is **atomic**.

#### Atomic?

Meaning that anyone can start reading at any section in a document and not have other portions of the document be dependent on some other portion of the document. (Unless it is explicitly stated within the section they are reading, to read another section)

Comment: I’m not sure this is quite on-topic — it seems to be about content-structuring in a specific style of technical writing, not specifically about language or usage.  It might be more on-topic for [writers.stackexchange](http://writers.stackexchange.com), perhaps?

Comment: Yes, please put this great question at Writers. We need some over there!

Answer (score 14):

- All terms are defined within the
  section.
- Either no outside references or
  optional ones, or include the
  information so the reader doesn't
  have to reference anything.
- Any background or history necessary
  to understand the material in the
  section is included.
- If applicable, include a paragraph
  with predictions about the future of
  the material or potential uses.
- Optionally, any potential
  controversies or questions regarding
  the material are at least
  acknowledged, if not necessarily
  debunked.

As a final check, compile your document with random
   sections, hand off to a beta reader,
   and ask the reader if anything led to
   a term which wasn't defined.
   Re-compile with different sections,
   lather, rinse, repeat.

Comment: Your checklist has two items so far, and one to verify the good functioning of the two before it. It'd be good to get the last item out of the list, I think it doesn't belong (in the list, I mean. It does belong in the answer).

Comment: @iajrz: okay, point taken. Edits above. better?

Comment: Yup, wonderful!! I didn't mean to sound harsh or rude, I really like your answers... just figured as I can't give a better answer I might as well help your answer be even better. :D

Comment: @iarjz: not at all. Constructive criticism is always welcome. :)